# Error: Illegal descriptor Type 0 for int 0

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, masm, protected-mode

I Can't switch to protected mode in a DOS EXE program written in MASM.

When loading the descriptor DOSBox gives the error:

> Illegal descriptor type 0 int 0.

I created a function to load the descriptor table with 3 descriptor Null, Code, Data. And I even turned on the A20 Line. I'm having trouble right after I use LGIT instruction. My code is:

```
.386p

GDT struct
limit_0_15 word ?
base_0_15  word ?
base_16_23 byte ?
access_byt byte ?
fl_limit   byte ?
base_24_31 byte ?
GDT ends

main_data segment use16
idt_start:
    db 800h dup (?)
idt_info:
    dw 2048
    dd idt_start

gdt_start:
nul_gdt GDT <0,0,0,0,0,0>
c32_gdt GDT <0,0,0,0,0,0>
d32_gdt GDT <0,0,0,0,0,0>
gdt_info:
    dw gdt_info - gdt_start - 1
    dd gdt_start

main_data ends

main_code segment use16
assume cs:main_code, ds:main_data, ss:stack16
_start:

mov  ax,main_data
mov  ds,ax
mov  ax,code16
mov  es,ax
call es:[Check_A20]
call es:[Set_A20]
call es:[Check_A20]
call es:[Create_GDT]

mov  bx,gdt_info
lgdt fword ptr[bx]

mov  bx,idt_info
lidt fword ptr[bx]

mov  eax,cr0
or   eax,1
mov  cr0,eax

jmp clear_prefetch_queue
nop
nop
clear_prefetch_queue:

mov  eax,0ffffh
mov  ebx,0fh
div  ebx

exit:
mov  ah,4ch
int  21h
main_code ends



code16 segment use16

Wait_8042_command proc ; wait for the kbd controller to get ready to take in commands
in   al,64h
test al,2
jnz  Wait_8042_command
ret
Wait_8042_command endp

Wait_8042_data proc   ; wait for the kbd controller to get ready to take in data
in   al,64h
test al,1
jz   Wait_8042_data
ret
Wait_8042_data endp

Check_A20 proc
pushf
push ds
push es
push di
push si

cli
xor  ax,ax
mov  es,ax
mov  di,500h
not  ax
mov  ds,ax
mov  si,510h

mov  al,byte ptr es:[di]
push ax
mov  al,byte ptr ds:[si]
push ax

mov  byte ptr es:[di],0
mov  byte ptr ds:[si],0ffh
cmp  byte ptr es:[di],0ffh

pop  ax
mov  byte ptr ds:[si],al
pop  ax
mov  byte ptr es:[di],al

mov  ax,0
je   check_a20_exit
mov  ax,1

check_a20_exit:
pop  si
pop  di
pop  es
pop  ds
popf
retf
Check_A20 endp

Set_A20 proc
cli
call Wait_8042_command
mov  al,0ADh             ;set command to disable kbd
out  64h,al

call Wait_8042_command
mov  al,0d0h
out  64h,al              ;read from input

call Wait_8042_data
in   al,60h              ;read input from kbd
push ax

call Wait_8042_command
mov  al,0d1h             ;write to output
out  64h,al

call Wait_8042_command
pop  ax
or   al,2
out  60h,al

call Wait_8042_command
mov  al,0AEh            ;enable kbd controller
out  64h,al

call Wait_8042_command
sti
retf
Set_A20 endp

Create_GDT proc
push ds
mov  ax,main_data
mov  ds,ax

;NULL Descriptor
;mov  cx,4
;rep  stosw
;code32 gdt initialized
mov  c32_gdt.limit_0_15, 0ffffh
mov  c32_gdt.base_0_15,  0h
mov  c32_gdt.base_16_23, 0h
mov  c32_gdt.access_byt, 9ah
mov  c32_gdt.fl_limit,   0cfh
mov  c32_gdt.base_24_31, 0h
;data32 gdt initialized
mov  d32_gdt.limit_0_15, 0ffffh
mov  d32_gdt.base_0_15,  0h
mov  d32_gdt.base_16_23, 0h
mov  d32_gdt.access_byt, 92h
mov  d32_gdt.fl_limit,   0cfh
mov  d32_gdt.base_24_31, 0h

pop  ds
retf
Create_GDT endp


code16 ends


code32 segment use32
mov  eax,0ffffh ;test garbage
mov  ebx,0fh
div  ebx
code32 ends

data32 segment use32

data32 ends


stack16 segment stack use16
    dw 200h dup (?)
stack16 ends

end _start
```

Comment: @MichaelPetch Apologies, I removed it in case of word limit, adding it now

Comment: @MichaelPetch I'm using MASM and it also does the same, doesn't need to specify FAR JMP or something, I added the link to the code

Comment: @MichaelPetch here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/19sNGstCMjoa3IR54Z6N-zRuD5w2W6E6Bp7wsH8xO4-8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I think the immediate cause of the problem is that the div instruction causes an overflow fault and the IDT isn’t yet initialized. (Div overflows because edx isn’t zero.)

Comment: As I suggested earlier you need to convert segment:offset addresses to linear addresses when dealing with the base of the GDT and IDT as well as the FAR JMP. A FAR JMP is required to get into protected mode by setting CS to a 32-bit code selector. I modified your MASM code and put it here: http://www.capp-sysware.com/misc/stackoverflow/55321878/pmdos.asm   . Are you able to run it? If it works it should print 'MDP` in white on magenta in the uppr left hand corner of the screen.

Comment: Be aware just because you set an IDT with LIDT doesn't make it useful. You need to populate it with interrupt gates before you can enable interrupts. Once in protected mode you can't do DOS or BIOS calls. My code simply does HLT to put your protected mode code into a do nothing wait state. As prl points out your `DIV` instruction will likely fail with an overflow if you don't clear EDX first. A failure will crash since you have no interrupt gates defined in your IDT (which includes the interrupt gate that handles division exceptions)

Comment: Is the #DE from `div` expected?  If you're using that to test your IDT setup, then you should make sure EDX is non-zero.  But if it's unexpected, then that part of the question is a duplicate.

Comment: @PeterCordes : this isn't really a duplicate. Even if he had a #DE handler this code still fails since the IDT isn't being loaded from the right memory address. The GDT also doesn't get loaded properly either.and the code doesn't properly enter 32-bit protected mode as the OP says he's trying to achieve. He only makes it as far as quasi 16-bit protected mode. This question is valid in the context of writing a DOS EXE (not COM or bootloaders) )program that may be located at arbitrary segments and the issue of linear addresses. I'm voting to  reopen this because I can provide a reasonable answer

Comment: This question is a continuation of the OPs previous question about loading of GDTs etc. It is clear that the main line of questioning is the OP attempting to enter protected mode from a DOS EXE program without the use of a protected mode interface (like VCPI/DPMI etc)

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Yeah, [8086 assembly on DOSBox: Bug with idiv instruction?](//stackoverflow.com/q/43574914) only covered the thing that revealed the incorrectly-configured IDT anyway.  Trying to do anything else with the machine after switching would have soon led to similar problems.  Closing as a duplicate for #DE was not the most useful way to do with this question as far as making SO a useful repository of Q&As.

Comment: @PeterCordes : What I will admit to is I was trying to decide if I should close it as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/54772558/3857942 . It is close, but that question involves FASM but more importantly the question used a relocation technique. The segments this OP has set up lends towards an answer that doesn't use relocation but modified the base address of some of the GDT descriptors to be non-zero. The latter reason is the one that had me not bring down the dupe hammer earlier.

Comment: @MichaelPetch us there any reference material that I should be reading. And on how to be more efficient, I just barely started asm

Comment: What you are doing here is not easy requiring a real understanding of how things work and also how to deal with issues involving DOS, segmentation, and relocation. I know experienced developers who know x86 assembly that would get caught off guard by the issues raised in this question.The Intel manuals are one place to get detailed info on each instructions. I would recommend learning assembly doing something less complex. A bootloader would even be an easier starting point (and you can get info on entering protected mode on [OSDev wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page) ).

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you chose to write code (being new to assembly) for the complex task of entering protected mode specifically from DOS?

Comment: @MichaelPetch I have made some assembly programs of my own and I was using the intel's manual too for the protected mode, it's just someone who's teaching me asked me to it and figure stuff on my own and I've faced segmentation a lot but it's just always something new everytime, that means I'm lacking some knowledge, so that's why I asked for some reference material. I was supposed to be making an animation code as I made a bmp printing one. And trust me the man in question is one of the bests. But I need to figure out my own problems

Comment: One always has to be aware in real mode that there is an implied or explicit segment on each memory operand in an instruction. The segment and the offset of a memory operand combine together to form a pointer to a specific physcal/linear address. One of the better tutorial on segmentation and the calculation involved can be found here: https://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/Segments.html

Comment: I'm familiar with real mode's segment and offset and 1MB of memory being used. Made a lot of programs in real mode, this was my first try with Protected Mode so I guess messed few things up. By the way heartily thankful for you time and help :D